# Streamlit Sessions State for Nested Buttons

Tags: python, frameworks, session-state, streamlit

I am trying to use session state in streamlit to have a two nested button in which first button click shows recommended movies and second submit button submits a review by user on which a model of sentiment analysis is working. But nested buttons require session state so i tried session state but always getting an error.  Below is the code.

```py
if 'rec_btn' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.rec_btn= False
    
    def callback():
        st.session_state.rec_btn = True
    
    if st.button('RECOMMEND',key = 'rec_btn'):
      col1, col2, col3 = st.columns(3)
     
      with col1:
          st.image(output_images[0])
          st.markdown(output_names[0].upper())
          review = st.text_input(f"How much you liked the movie {output_names[0]}")
          if st.button('submit',on_click=callback):
                review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]','',review)
                review = tf_idf_vectorizer.transform([review])
                ans = model_sentiment.predict(review)
                if  ans == 0:
                    review = 'Thanks for your positive review'
                else:
                    review = 'Sorry for your negative review'
                st.write(review)
```

I am always getting error:

```
StreamlitAPIException: Values for st.button, st.download_button, st.file_uploader, 
and st.form cannot be set using st.session_state.
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem was with how i was using session state for button. Which i was able to understand using this code below. In this way nested button can work together.

```py
import streamlit as st
button1 = st.button('Recommend')
if st.session_state.get('button') != True:

    st.session_state['button'] = button1 # Saved the state

if st.session_state['button'] == True:

    st.write("button1 is True")

    if st.button('Check 2'):

        st.write("Do your logic here")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update** I *am* sure why this is the case (dawned on my as soon as I  submitted this answer).
I *am* using the key "dialog" elsewhere in my code in st.session_state. In the other case, it's not a widget key, just a state key - so I missed that. Simply changing the name of the key worked for me.

TL;DR if you find your way to this page because you got that particular error, make sure you're not using a key for your widget that's used for something else.

For your case @Tushar, I know your reuse of the key was deliberate to so changing it won't help. But you probably will get help from the documentation here on [Buttons to modify or reset other widgets](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/button-behavior-and-examples#buttons-to-modify-or-reset-other-widgets)

---

Original answer from way back - oh 5 minutes ago:

I'm not sure why this is the case but I had this exact error using nothing more than a button with a literal string for the key. The key was not used elsewhere and had nothing to do with session state. In short this fails:

```
if button("okay", key="dialog"):
    # doesn't matter what I do here - that line throw an exception
```

with

```
StreamlitAPIException: Values for st.button, st.download_button, st.file_uploader, and st.form cannot be set using st.session_state.
```

where this works fine:

```
if button("okay"):
    # no key, no problem?!
```

I *hate* giving an answer that I don't explain - but in case you end up here, it might save you some hassle.